# Insert SQL statements in php bind_param function

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am trying to use sql commands preparation to avoid injection but I can't figure out how can I use SQL *statements* in the bind_param function. My code is this :

```php
function saveContent($POST_DATA) {
    $conn = new mysqli("HOST", "USER", "PASSWORD");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $command = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, dateHappening, time, topic, 
        subtopic, extraMessage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        
        $command->bind_param("ssssss", $POST_DATA["inputTitre"], $POST_DATA["inputDate"], 
        $POST_DATA["inputHour"], $POST_DATA["selectTopic"], $POST_DATA["selectSubTopic"], 
        $POST_DATA["inputMessage"]);
        $command->execute();
        $command->close();
        $conn->close();

    }
}
```

The thing here is that I would like `extraMessage` to be NULL if it is blank (because this field is not mandatory). To optimize this code I would have liked to use something like

```sql
NULLIF($POST_DATA["inputMessage"], "")
```

Is inserting the statement above in the bind_param function possible ?

Comment: No. You have to write all the SQL expressions in the query and only insert the placeholder where the value goes. So, essentially, you would put `NULLIF(?, "")` in the query instead of just a `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved (see comment under my question) :

> No. You have to write all the SQL expressions in the query and only insert the placeholder where the value goes. So, essentially, you would put `NULLIF(?, "")` in the query instead of just a `?`. –